# C++ vector: unused capacity

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am a new comer for C++, I am currently working on this class schedule project and the following is my add_course function. I am storing student's id, semester, and list of classes in a map. It works(I can add course to student and see it when I print a student's schedule) but every time I run the code, an exception always pop up :

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<course *,std::allocator<course *> > >::_Myend(...) returned 0xC.
```

I am confusing, why is this happening. Does it mean my vector is having more capacity than it needs ?

```
void add_course(map<int, map<int, vector<course *> * > > &DB, int semester, int id, course c) {
    const string a = c.name;
    course* b = new course(a, c.section, c.credits);
    if (DB[id].empty()) {
        vector<course*> *p2 = new vector<course*>;
        (*p2) = { b };
        DB[id][semester] = p2; 
        return;
    }
    else
        DB[id][semester]->push_back(b);
    return;
}
```

Comment: This looks like quite the abuse of dynamic allocation and looks heavily influenced by Java or C#. In C++, value semantics are strongly encouraged. There isn't really any need for all of those `new` and getting rid of them would greatly simplify your code. For example, just `course b{a, c.section, c.credits};` seems preferable, same with `std::vector<course> p2{ std::move(b) };`.

Comment: I would encourage you to rewrite your code without using any pointers, `new` or `delete`, and simply use `vector` and `course` by value. It will simplify things greatly. If you need shared ownership, consider using `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Vectors almost always have more capacity then they need for performance reasons and it's certainly not a cause for a run time error. "read access violation" implies an error in how you handle pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code assumes that if `DB[id]` has *any* semesters, it has the semester `semester`:

```
if (DB[id].empty()) {
   // ...
}
else
    DB[id][semester]->push_back(b);
```

If that's not true, if it has *some* semester but not this one, then you're not catching that, and you're `push_back`ing on a default-constructed null pointer. This means your program has undefined behaviour, and today is the reason for the crash.

Instead you could try:

```
if (!DB[id].count(semester)) {
   // ...
}
else
    DB[id][semester]->push_back(b);
```

… which actually checks for the existence of the specific inner map element.

You would be much better off without all this dynamic allocation, though:

```
void add_course(
   map<int, map<int, vector<course>>>& DB,
   const int semester,
   const int id,
   const course c
)
{
    DB[id][semester].emplace_back(c.name, c.section, c.credits);
}
```

Isn't that nicer?!

Comment: And this has nothing at all to do with "unused capacity"; I'm not quite sure where you got that idea!

Comment: Thanks!  I just found this problem 2 min ago. Now I have to deal with memory leak.

Comment: @WilliamMo I encourage you to spend more than two minutes on a problem before resorting to asking us for help!